# Thread return and synchronize

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I am making a card game application. I have 2 threads:
Thread **curr** = here is saved current thread(JavaFx thread)
Thread **proHs** = here is a brain of app, which runs method through Interface
I want to stop thread **proHs** stop for a second until I choose one of these two buttons **mam** **nemam**
Then I must return **true** or **false**.
I appreciate any sugestion or advice. **Thanks!**

I have tried infinity loop

```
public boolean biddingStep(int gt) { //above this method is @Override, I can't post this with it
    System.out.println("  ");
    System.out.println("I HAVE OR NOT PART");
    try {
        proHs.wait();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print(e);
    }
    panelLicitace.setVisible(true);
    mam.setVisible(true);
    nemam.setVisible(true);
    return false;//there would be the resolution of button "mam" or "nemam"
}
```

EDIT #1

What I want from you:

```
public boolean biddingStep(int gt) { //above this method is @Override, I can't post this with it
    System.out.println("  ");
    System.out.println("I HAVE OR NOT PART");
    panelLicitace.setVisible(true);
    mam.setVisible(true);
    nemam.setVisible(true);
    // HERE a code i want
    //1. stop proHS thread
    //2. loop program, wait for input from 2 buttons
    //3. return true or false
}
```

Comment: Either `wait/notify` on a shared `Object`, or `await/signal` on a shared `Condition`, or use something like a `BlockingQueue` and have the JavaFX thread put actions in the queue which the other thread would take and execute. Those are some options for thread communication, but without a [mcve] we can't answer your question or see problems with your current approach, if any; however, the `proHs.wait()` does not look correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to understand that wait() is Object class method, so it is like a particular thread is waiting for some action related to Object. 
So here if **biddingStep(int gt)** is being called under proHs thread and you want to stop the proHs thread ,basically to wait until a particular button is selected then you need to put the wait on some object,in general it should be the Object on which some action needs to happen. You need list of below steps here:

1. proHs object reference.
2. put a lock on proHs object.
3. call proHs.wait().

From second thread you will do below operation:
 1. put lock on proHs object inside buttonClickListener
        second thread.)
 2. call proHs.notify().

```
class InterfaceImpl {
    Thread proHs;
    boolean btnResponse;
    public boolean biddingStep(int gt) {
        System.out.println("  ");
        System.out.println("I HAVE OR NOT PART");
        panelLicitace.setVisible(true);
        mam.setVisible(true);
        nemam.setVisible(true);
        // HERE a code i want
        //1. stop proHS thread
        synchronized(proHs) {
            proHs.wait();
            //2. loop program, wait for input from 2 buttons
            //3. return true or false
            return btnResponse;
        }
    }   

    // This method should be called from another thread
    public boolean btnClickListener() { 
        btnResponse = true or false
        synchronized(proHs) {
            proHs.notify();
        }  
    }
}
```

Here biddingStep() method should be called prior to the btnClickListener(), so that once thread will be waiting then another thread will notify it.